# C++: candidate template ignored when iterating over tuple

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, iteration, c++-concepts

I am attempting to iterate through a tuple using the following code:

```cpp
template <std::size_t I = 0, typename... Ts>
    requires (I >= sizeof...(Ts))
static inline auto consume_all(std::tuple<Ts...>&&, auto) -> void {}

template <std::size_t I = 0, typename... Ts>
    requires (I < sizeof...(Ts))
static inline auto consume_all(std::tuple<Ts...>&& tup, auto f) -> void {
    f(std::get<I>(tup));
    consume_all<I + 1, Ts...>(tup, f);
}
```

From what I can see there is nothing wrong with the above definition. However when I try to call it...:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename T>
concept unary = requires(F&& f, T&& t) {
    {
        f(t)
    } -> std::convertible_to<T>;
};

//...
//in struct definition:

    const std::tuple<Fs...> funcs;

//...
//in method definition:

                consume_all<Fs...>(
                        funcs,
                        [=, &t]<unary<T> F>(F f) {t = f(t);}
                );
```

...I receive a compile time error saying that both templates have been ignored:

```
No matching function for call to 'consume_all' in instantiation of member function 'chain<int, [function-typenames]>'
...
candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'I'
candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'I'
```

I cannot see the issue as the combination of `... >= I` and `... < I` should be all encompassing.

**Edit:**

When specifying `I` (`consume_all<0, Fs...>`) the candidate templates are still ignored although now they yield a more descriptive error:

```cpp
No matching function for call to 'consume_all'
...
candidate template ignored: //issue
deduced type 'tuple<...>' of 1st parameter does not match adjusted type
'const tuple<...>' of argument
[with I = 0, Ts = <(lambda)>, f:auto = (lambda)]

candidate template ignored: //rightfully
constraints not satisfied
[with I = 0, Ts = <(lambda)>, auto:3 = (lambda)]
because '0U >= sizeof...(Ts)' (0 >= 1) evaluated to false
```

Comment: BTW, in C++17: `std::apply([&](auto&&... args){ (f(args), ...); }, tup);`.

Comment: `std::tuple<Ts...>&&` is not forwarding-reference, so you need `consume_all(std::move(funcs), lambda)`

Comment: a [mre] would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at @Jarod42 's comment I have found a better way to iterate through a tuple that side-steps the template issue.

Defining `consume_all` as an iterative function is not the way to go.

Instead `consume_all` should be defined using `std::apply(func, tup)` which parses the tuple `tup` as the argument for `func`.

This now converts the problem of iterating through a tuple into that of iterating through a parameter pack (which is easier).

**Iterating through the elements of a parameter pack:**

```cpp
template <typename F>
[[maybe_unused]] static inline void consume(F) {}
//^^^ Empty Base Case ^^^

template <typename F, typename Arg>
    requires std::invocable<F, Arg>
[[maybe_unused]] static inline void consume(F f, Arg arg) {
    f(arg);
}
//^^^ Single Arg Base Case ^^^

template <typename F, typename Arg, typename... Args>
    requires std::invocable<F, Arg>
static inline void consume(F f, Arg arg, Args... args) {
    f(arg);
    consume<F, Args...>(f, args...);
}
//^^^ Recursive General Case ^^^
```

Now that we have defined a function for consuming each element of a parm pack we can now properly define `consume_all`

**Redefining consume_all:**

```cpp
template <typename F, typename... Args>
[[maybe_unused]] static inline void consume_all(F f, std::tuple<Args...> tup) {
    std::apply(
            [&f](auto&&... args){
                consume(f, args...);
            },
            tup
    );
}
```

**Solving the original problem:**

```cpp
        consume_all(
                [&t]<unary<T> F>(F f) {t = f(t);},
                funcs
                );
```

I hope this helps anyone else with a similar problem

Comment: From my comment even your (recursive) `consume` is not needed, fold expression `consume(f, args...);` -> `(f(args), ...);`.

Comment: And `consume_all`'s requirements: `requires (std::invocable<F, Args> && ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your call to

```
consume_all<Fs...>
```

you are missing `I`. You would need

```
consume_all<0, Fs...>
```

Comment: The `I` is optional as specified by `std::size_t I = 0`. It defaults to zero.

Comment: @Vye `I` might be optional but as it is the first argument it will bind to the first element of `Fs...`

Comment: @Alan Birtles I have now learnt that Parameter packs bind weirdly. **However** this answer still does not solve the question.

Comment: Logically, idea is to omit all template parameters.